# XSL find position with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am learning the XSL and Xpath syntax and I have some small problems. My goal is to find out the warranty of a series of products. This warranty may be contained within 'features' or 'options'.

```
<features>
<linea> asdasd </linea>
<linea> warranty of 9 moths </linea>
</features> 

<opcion>
<linea> warranty of 1 year </linea>
</opcion>
```

So far I have no problems, I have made a 'for-each' and I am able to go through each one. but I am not able to extract the number of the sentence For example:

warranty 1 year (I need to extract the number of this sentence)

Can you help me?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="tienda4.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<tienda>
  <nombre>La tiendecilla</nombre>
  <telefono>953 87 12 23</telefono>
  <url etiqueta="URL: ">http://www.tiendecilla.es</url>
  <producto>
    <codigo>92</codigo>
    <cantidad>10</cantidad>
    <articulo>Radio-Casette</articulo>
    <seccion>Electrónica</seccion>
    <marca>Sanyo</marca>
    <modelo>MKJ-800</modelo>
    <caracteristicas>
      <linea>Auto-reverse</linea>
      <linea>Dolby-sorround</linea>
      <linea>Doble pletina</linea>
      <linea>Ecualizador de cinco bandas</linea>
      <linea>Garantía de 9 meses.</linea>
    </caracteristicas>
    <precio moneda="euro">90</precio>
  </producto>
  <producto>
    <codigo>103</codigo>
    <cantidad>50</cantidad>
    <articulo>Reloj Cocina</articulo>
    <seccion>Electrónica</seccion>
    <marca>Kenwood</marca>
    <modelo>Blue ONE</modelo>
    <caracteristicas>
      <linea>Varios diseños</linea>
    </caracteristicas>
    <opciones nombre="color" tipo="unica">
      <opcion valor="rojo"/>
      <opcion valor="azul"/>
      <opcion valor="blanco"/>
    </opciones>
    <opciones nombre="forma" tipo="unica">
      <opcion valor="cuadrado"/>
      <opcion valor="triangular"/>
      <opcion valor="redondo"/>
      <linea>Garantía de 6 meses.</linea>
    </opciones>
    <precio moneda="euro">12</precio>
  </producto>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="tienda">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
      <body>
      <h2>Tabla de tiendas</h2>
       <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Sección</th>
        <th>Articulo</th>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Garantia</th>
        </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="producto">
         <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="seccion"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="articulo"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="marca"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="modelo"/></td>
          <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="caracteristicas"> 
            <xsl:if test="contains(., 'Garantía')">
            <xsl:value-of select="linea"/> (this only show me the first line, not who's contains the warranty)
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>    
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number from the string "warranty of 1 year" you can do it in a couple of ways:

Using the [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) function:

```
translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')
```

the internal call will remove any characters from the string, and only yield the numbers, the outer call will remove any other characters from the string except the numbers that the inner function returned.

Or you can use [substring-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) and [subtring-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after):

```
substring-before(substring-after(., 'warranty of '), ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<xsl:for-each select="producto">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="seccion"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="articulo"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="marca"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="modelo"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="(caracteristicas/linea | opciones/linea)[contains(., 'Garantía')]"/> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

Sorry, I missed the 'extract number' part. Use the double `translate()` method as explained by Ayoub_B.

Answer (score -1):

Besides there are other problems with your stylesheet, replace

```
<xsl:value-of select="linea"/>
```

whith

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Garantía de '),' meses')"/>
```